# Displaying text that updates with pygame

Tags: python, text, pygame

What I need to happen, and what the text will be used for, is to display the day and temperature above the grid the ball moves around. Every 20 directional changes equals a day and each day has a temperature associated with it, so as the program runs, the text has to change respective to the current day and temperature. In order to achieve what's needed, my output has to be one that would constantly update and continue for a simulated year. How would I do this?

I wrote code that would display what I want, but doesn't do it entirely.
What it does is displays, ("Day: 5", "Temp: 6"), centered with a black background of the text that doesnt span across the entire screen. It also doesn't update as the program runs.

My desired output is for the text to not have parentheses or quotes, to span across the entire bottom of the screen (when running the code, there is a section without the grid), and to update as the program loops.  How can I do these things with the code I currently have?

Note: The current code is not my actual program, but it a rewritten code for the current question at hand.

*Note: I have my days and temperatures taken from an excel file.*

```py
import pygame as pg
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('daysTemp.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

temps = []
days = []
for k in range(1,sheet.nrows):
        temps.append(int(sheet.row_values(k)[-2]))
        days.append(int(sheet.row_values(k)[-1]))

d = ("day: ", days[5])
t = ("temp: ", temps[5])

pg.init() 

white = (255, 255, 255) 
green = (0, 255, 0) 
black = (0, 0, 0) 

# define measurements
WIDTH, HEIGHT, MARGIN = 10, 10, 1
GRIDX, GRIDY = 90, 35

class GridObject(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, grid, *groups):
        super().__init__(groups)

        # create image from grid
        self.grid = grid
        self.gridsize = (len(grid[0]), len(grid))
        imgsize = self.gridsize[0]*(WIDTH+MARGIN), self.gridsize[1]*(HEIGHT+MARGIN)
        self.image = pg.Surface(imgsize, flags=pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
        col = (1, 1, 1)
        for c in range(self.gridsize[0]):
            for r in range(self.gridsize[1]):
                if self.grid[r][c] == 1:
                    rect = [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * c + MARGIN, (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * r + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT]
                    pg.draw.rect(self.image, col, rect)

# set the pygame window name
screen = pg.display.set_mode((GRIDX * (WIDTH+MARGIN) + MARGIN, GRIDY * (HEIGHT+MARGIN) + 50))
pg.display.set_caption('Show Text') 

# create a font object. 
font = pg.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 24) 

# create a text suface object, 
text = font.render(str(d + t), True, green, black) 

# create a rectangular text object
textRect = text.get_rect() 

# set the center of the rectangular object. 
textRect.center = ((GRIDX * (WIDTH+MARGIN) + 50) // 2, (GRIDY * (HEIGHT+MARGIN) + 50) // 2) 

# infinite loop 
while True:
    for event in pg.event.get() :
        if event.type == pg.QUIT :
            pg.quit()
            quit()

        screen.fill(black)

        # Draw the grid and add values to the cells
        for row in range(GRIDY):
            for column in range(GRIDX):
                rect = [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN, (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT]
                color = white
                pg.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)

        screen.blit(text, textRect)
        pg.display.update()
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the code?

Comment: I updated the question, but to reiterate, I want the text to not have parentheses or quotes around it and to be positioned in the bottom of the screen in accordance to the output if the code (there is a black section where the grid isnt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the parentheses and quotes, you can use the `join` function. you do need to have all elements in the tuple strings, so you would need to have `d = ("day: ", str(days[5]))` and `t = ("temp: ", str(temps[5]))`

then:

`"".join(d) + ", " + "".join(t)` instead of `str(d + t)`

output:  Day: 5, Temp: 6

To change the values, you need to change it in the loop, so add `d = ("day: ", str(days[i]))` and `t = ("temp: ", str(temps[i]))` in the loop and increment i by 1 in the loop.

To have it at the bottom of the screen, change the y value of TextRect to the bottom of the screen, so `textRect.center = ((GRIDX * (WIDTH+MARGIN) + 50) // 2, (GRIDY * (HEIGHT+MARGIN) + 50))`. getting rid of the //2 works.